# Ubuntu VM with Cups Server and docker container with pycups: cups.IPPError: (1030, 'The printer or class does not exist.')

Tags: ubuntu, python, printing, docker, cups

I have an Ubuntu VM with the cups server installed, configured and running.
I can print to every printer from the web interface with no problems.
Inside this VM there is a docker container with a python flask app where you can POST pdfs and they get saved in a temporary path. Then it uses pycups to print those files to a CLASS called "DOCUMENTOS".
This fails everytime saying:

```
cups.IPPError: (1030, 'The printer or class does not exist.')
```

I've tried to call directly to the printer (HP_LaserJet_Pro_M118dw) but the result is the same.

In the docker container I have setup a bind:

```
/tmp -> /tmp
```

which results in this **filename** passed to pycups printFile function:

```
/tmp/print-daemon/1696440073890032106.pdf
```

Python list printers:

```
printers = self.conn.getPrinters()
printer_names = list(printers.keys())
print(f'printers {printer_names}', flush=True)
```

Result in log:

```
printers ['DOCUMENTOS', 'HP_LaserJet_Pro_M118dw']
```

Relevant python code:

```
cups.setServer(cups_server)
cups.setPort(631)
cups.setEncryption(3)
cups.setUser("user")
cups.setPasswordCB(self.__passwordCB)
self.conn = cups.Connection(host=cups_server, port=631)
...
self.conn.printFile(printer='DOCUMENTOS', filename=filename, title='', options={})
```

lpstat -v:

```
dispositivo para DOCUMENTOS: ///dev/null
dispositivo para HP_LaserJet_Pro_M118dw: socket://192.168.5.XX
```

/etc/cups/cupsd.conf

```
LogLevel debug2
PageLogFormat
MaxLogSize 0
ErrorPolicy retry-job
Port 631
Listen /run/cups/cups.sock
Browsing On
BrowseLocalProtocols dnssd
DefaultAuthType Basic
WebInterface Yes
...
```

/var/log/cups/error_log

```
D [04/Oct/2023:17:33:13 +0000] Get-Printer-Attributes file:///dev/null
d [04/Oct/2023:17:33:13 +0000] get_printer_attrs(0x5631dc6e8290[6], file:///dev/null)
D [04/Oct/2023:17:33:13 +0000] Get-Printer-Attributes client-error-not-found: The printer or class does not exist.
D [04/Oct/2023:17:33:13 +0000] [Client 6] Returning IPP client-error-not-found for Get-Printer-Attributes (file:///dev/null) from 172.18.0.4.
```

[Pastebin cupsd full error log](https://pastebin.com/YpMsydpb)